# Importing MS Access dataabse in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access

How can we inport MS Access dataabse in Mysql database using mysql prompt ?

I know  it  is possible.

any help ?

Comment: what does a requirement to 'use mysql prompt' mean and why do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

You will find quite a lot of resources [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/active-grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLyog as a GUI for MySQL, which I'm very happy with. It has a utility to import data from a number of sources, including MS Access. There is a free Community Edition available, although I find it totally worthwhile to pay the small annual subscription fee for the Ultimate version. HTH.